# Multiple copies of artifacts or minerals

Tags: stardew-valley

Besides some of the crystals, I am having a hard time finding a use for my multiple copies of artifacts or other types of minerals.

Will I ever find a use for my left over artifacts or minerals after I donated the first one to the Museum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate artifacts and minerals can simply be sold or put into your delivery box to make extra money. As mentioned in the comments, the minerals may also be used as gifts for villagers or as materials for crafting. A limited selection of artifacts are also good gifts for select villagers. Aside from these uses, they serve no other purposes once you've donated one to the museum.

To give you some examples, Abigail loves Amethysts, the Dwarf likes to receive dwarven artifacts as gifts (scrolls, helmet), and Earth Crystals are used in the recipe for Mayonnaise Machines. If you prefer to sell these items instead, artifacts and minerals are all worth a decent amount of gold (except for dwarven scrolls), and are a nice way to have some extra income.

Comment: Don't forget that Minerals can in fact make good friendship presents or are even used in crafting in some cases.

Comment: Some minerals are also used in crafting, as noted in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258965/what-minerals-are-used-in-crafting/258984#258984).

Comment: Are you sure it's *Abigail* that loves Amethysts, and not Emily (who is revealed to love Amethysts via a quest)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, Abigail loves them, and so does Emily, and so does the Dwarf.. But the point of the answer was not to be an exhaustive list of stuff that each villager does and doesn't like. It was an example.

Comment: No, that's cool, I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't a typo. :)

Comment: Minerals can also be the object of a fetch quest. I've had Abigail ask for Aquamarine, and Clint ask for Topaz.

Answer (score 1):

You can ship them for extra money, or give them to people as Gifts. I know that the Dwarven Scrolls only sell for 1G but make decent gifts for the Dwarf, as one example.