# What Minerals are used in crafting?

Tags: stardew-valley

It appears that minerals and artifacts are mainly used to donate to the museum. But some, like Earth Crystals, are used in crafting recipes. What other minerals need to be saved for crafting purposes and what can just be sold after the first one has been donated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross-referencing the [Crafting](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crafting) and [Minerals](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Minerals) pages of the Stardew Valley Wiki, the minerals that can be used in crafting are:

- Aquamarine (Marble Brazier)
- Diamond (Ring of Yoba)
- Quartz (refined quartz for numerous recipes)
- Fire Quartz (Slime Egg Press)
- Frozen Tear (Warrior Ring)
- Earth Crystal (Mayonnaise Machine, Sturdy Ring)
- Marble (Marble Brazier)
- Coal (20 crafting recipes, use in furnace for refining ore and quartz)
- Copper Ore (Cherry Bomb, Flute Block, Drum Block, Furnace, copper bars for numerous recipes)
- Iron Ore (Bomb, iron bars for numerous recipes)
- Gold Ore (Mega Bomb, gold bars for numerous recipes)
- Iridium Ore (iridium bars for numerous recipes)

Artifacts seem to have very little use in any crafting. According to the [Artifacts](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Artifacts) page:

> Artifacts aside from the Ancient Seed are not used for Crafting or
>   requested by Villagers for quests.

Minerals can also be used for [Bundles](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Bundles) in the community center:

- Aquamarine (Dye Bundle)
- Quartz (Geologist's Bundle)
- Fire Quartz (Geologist's Bundle)
- Frozen Tear (Geologist's Bundle)
- Earth Crystal (Geologist's Bundle)
- Frozen Geode (Field Research Bundle)
- Copper/Iron/Gold Bar (Blacksmith's Bundle)

Comment: Minerals can also be the object of a fetch quest, so it's worth keeping one of each type around, whether they're useful for crafting or not.

Comment: @Nathan This is true, I didn't add them here because the question specifically asked about ones used in crafting. I suppose the bundles technically aren't about crafting either... but some are, and some help further crafting. But you're correct, it'd be advantageous to keep at least one or two of each for the `Gathering` quests from Clint, and the `Delivery` help wanted quests (described on the [Stardew Valley wiki page](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Quests#Gathering) under those same headings).